# After Cellphone repair shop - power button damged and cant switch back to bright mode

Tags: iphone, repair, lightning, damage

I brought my iPhone7 to a cellphone repair shop to replace my lightning connector and exchange the battery.

Unfortunately after the replacement, my home button does not trigger anymore (interestingly, touchid still works). Also dark mode is enabled and I CANT set it back to bright mode. When I want to press on the bright mode button in the settings menue, it just does nothing! How weird is that!?

Screen works fine, although force touch also does not work anymore.

And now the strange thing: the guy tried to fix it - put in another lightning connector module, even tried another original display module (with integrated home button). Nothing fixed the home button!

He will give it a try tomorrow again.

Any ideas on what’s going on here?

Comment: I could meanwhile switch back to bright mode by tripple touching the virtual home button. At least that!